# CakePHP : How to include id in $this->render()

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

I'm sorry for nooby question.

But how can I make $this->render and send an id to it..

I have a func called test which have all the data and view..

But I want to use tcpdf to output the view as pdf.. so is there anyway to use $this->render('test' with an id in the parameter ?.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set variables for use in a view with [`this->set`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/978/Interacting-with-Views).  All you need to do is call `set` before `render`.  The declaration for `set` is:

```
set(string $var, mixed $value)
```

Comment: yeap.. i just do that.. its working.. :) but now my problem is with tcpdf..when i move the code to tcpdf.. its says something about undefined index : cols in tcpdf blablabla.. why is it happening actually?

Comment: Well this is a separate question, so it is advised that you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).